# Two kinds of equation labels within one paper

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments

I have looked high and low for an answer to the following (including on this site, Google, etc.) without success, and I hope someone may be able to answer it (and if it is a repeat of something answered elsewhere, a link to that would be swell).

My question has to do with setting up two different equation-labeling environments within the same paper (produced via LaTeX using `amsart`).  I would like to have two *distinct* equation commands, say `{equation}` and `{eqn}`, so I can write things like

```
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
```

and

```
\numberwithin{eqn}{subsubsection}
```

in the topmatter so that by choosing either

```
\begin{equation}....\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{eqn}...\end{eqn}
```

I will have the flexibility to arrange that automated labels of a displayed expression will appear in the style `(x.y.z)` or `(x.y.z.w)` at my discretion.  How is this done (ideally with a minimum of fuss)?

For other kinds of environments, such as `theorems`, `remarks`, etc., I know one can use the `{theoremstyle}` framework to define distinct commands (such as `{theorem}`, `{thm}` as well as `{remark}`, `{rem}`, etc.) which one creates in such a way so as to have different levels of numerical labeling appear (e.g. `Theorem x.y.z` versus `Theorem x.y.z.w`).  But I cannot figure out how to do the same with the labeling of displayed expressions, since it seems the word `equation` is reserved in LaTeX in a way that the word `theorem` is not (unless I am overlooking something well-known, which is entirely possible).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `tag` command defined by the `ams` bundle as follows

```
\newenvironment{eqn}{\refstepcounter{equation}\equation}{\tag{\thesubsection.\theequation}\endequation}
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{eqn}{\refstepcounter{equation}\equation}{\tag{\thesubsection.\theequation}\endequation}
\begin{document}

\subsection{test}
\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{eqn}
f(x)=x^2  
\end{eqn}
\begin{equation}
  G(x)=\cos(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I'll play around with this one too.  I'll wait for a bit before picking one official "answer" (though it seems meaningless, insofar as there can be multiple equally good answers).  Or maybe I don't need to pick a preferred answer, and leave it for readers to go with whatever they like best?

Answer (score 1):

It is a general idea, only for right equation numbers now. Some               deeper work is still needed. Additional LaTeX counter, called `eqn`, is defined.

You a suggesting a problems with labels' names. But they can be near arbitrary.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@definecounter{eqn}
\def\eqn{$$\refstepcounter{eqn}}
\def\endeqn{\eqno \hbox{\@eqnNum}$$\@ignoretrue}
\def\@eqnNum{{\normalfont \normalcolor (\theeqn)}}
\makeatother

\section{First}

\numberwithin{equation}{subsection} 

%and

\numberwithin{eqn}{subsubsection} 

in the topmatter so that by choosing either

\begin{equation} ....\end{equation}

or

\begin{eqn}...\end{eqn} 

\begin{equation} ....\end{equation}

or

\begin{eqn}...\end{eqn} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  This works really well.  I realize that the lack of a natural order structure on the integer lattice beyond dimension 1 creates some mild puzzles about making a systematic rule to deal with leaping from (7.4.1) to (7.4.3.1) without any (7.4.2)-type thing in between (which looks a bit funny to me, but such is life). So I will have to use a bit of judgement on what to employ, but having this option available to me now is super-useful.  It remains to be seen how cooperative a journal will be, invoking its "conventions" or whatever...