# Using two numbering systems at the same time

Tags: equations, numbering

Equations are normally numbered (1), (2), (3), etc., but I would also like some equations to be labeled (i), (ii), (iii). I would like to use both numbering systems at the same time. For example:

```
equation (1) <-- this is the label
equation (2)
equation (i)
equation (3)
equation (ii)
equation (4)
equation (5)
```

etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: I see these questions regularly and it makes me think, if there shouldn't be a more general and modular approach to it. Maybe there is already one, but I don't know it: The label should be created by a command `\putthelabel` which would be defined as something like `\labelformat\prelabel\theactuallabel\postlabel`. That way one could simply redefine `\theactuallabel` as `\myromanlabel` and afterwards put it back to `\thedefaultactuallabel`. Does anybody know of a package, which does it or how to simply change `amsmath` that way?

Comment: all the solutions offered so far work for one-line equations.  but do you also want this ability for, say, aligned equations and other multi-line structures?  that's going to be more complicated.

Comment: @Toscho `\tag` as in my answer

Comment: @barbarabeeton good point, see my update. I deliberately avoided the idea of trying to redefine all of the `ams` environments, and opted simply for `mytag`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple solution defining an environment, `eqn`, that gives `roman` numbering.

## If you want shared numbering

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newenvironment{eqn}{%
        \refstepcounter{equation}\equation}
        {\tag{\roman{equation}}\endequation}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{eqn}
f(x)=x^2  
\end{eqn}
\begin{equation}
  G(x)=\cos(x)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

## If you want separate numbering

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{eqn}
\newenvironment{eqn}{%
        \refstepcounter{eqn}\equation}
        {\tag{\roman{eqn}}\endequation}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eqn:linear}
  y=mx+b
\end{equation}
\begin{eqn}\label{eqn:quad}
f(x)=x^2  
\end{eqn}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:trig}
  G(x)=\cos(x)
\end{equation}
\begin{eqn}\label{eqn:bessel}
h(x)=J_n(x)
\end{eqn}
\begin{itemize}
  \item reference: \eqref{eqn:linear}
  \item reference: \eqref{eqn:quad}
  \item reference: \eqref{eqn:trig}
  \item reference: \eqref{eqn:bessel}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

## For multi-line equations

you can use the same idea, with the same counter and , for example, the command

```
\newcommand{\mytag}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\roman{equation}}}
```

if you want shared equation numbering, and

```
\newcommand{\mytag}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\tag{\roman{eqn}}}
```

if you want separate numbering.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{eqn}
%\newcommand{\mytag}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\tag{\roman{eqn}}}
\newcommand{\mytag}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\roman{equation}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    y    & =mx+b\label{eqn:linear}          \\
    f(x) & =x^2 \mytag\label{eqn:quad}      \\
    G(x) & =\cos(x) \label{eqn:trig}        \\
    h(x) & =J_n(x) \mytag\label{eqn:bessel} 
\end{align}
\begin{itemize}
    \item reference: \eqref{eqn:linear}
    \item reference: \eqref{eqn:quad}
    \item reference: \eqref{eqn:trig}
    \item reference: \eqref{eqn:bessel}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Your question is very similar to [Two kinds of equation labels within one paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144726/two-kinds-of-equation-labels-within-one-paper)

Comment: This is very simpel. The only problem is that the counters are not begin stepped up individually. In your example, the second reference should be `(i)` and last reference should be `(2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \label{a}
  a+b\\
 \label{b}
  c+d\\
 \label{c}
  e+f\tag{i}\\
 \label{d}
  g+h\\
 \label{e}
  i+j\tag{ii}\\
 \label{f}
  k+l\\
 \label{g}
  m+n
\end{align}

Equation~\eqref{a}.

Equation~\eqref{b}.

Equation~\eqref{c}.

Equation~\eqref{d}.

Equation~\eqref{e}.

Equation~\eqref{f}.

Equation~\eqref{g}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I might have misunderstood you (I'm not sure); do you want automatic numbering without having to use `\tag`?

Comment: Yes, I would like automatic numbering. Otherwise if I remove (i), I would have to manually shift all the other labels.

Comment: @AlanC I see that Francis has [answered your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144971/15874).

Answer (score 2):

It can be automatically achieved by defining a new environment. Let's call it `romanequation`:

```
\makeatletter

\newcounter{romanequation}

\def\incr@eqnumrom@n{\refstepcounter{romanequation}\let\incr@eqnumr\@empty}

\renewcommand{\theromanequation}{\roman{romanequation}}

\def\endmathdisplayroman#1{%
  \ifmmode \else \@badmath \fi
  \endmathdisplay@aroman
  $$%
  \global\let\df@label\@empty \global\let\df@tag\@empty
  \global\tag@false \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
  \global\@eqnswfalse
}

\def\endmathdisplay@aroman{%
  \if@eqnsw \gdef\df@tag{\tagform@\theromanequation}\fi
  \if@fleqn \@xp\endmathdisplay@fleqn
  \else \ifx\df@tag\@empty \else \veqno \alt@tag \df@tag \fi
    \ifx\df@label\@empty \else \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum\dspbrk@lvl>\m@ne
    \postdisplaypenalty -\@getpen\dspbrk@lvl
    \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne
  \fi
}

\def\print@eqnumrom@n{\tagform@\theromanequation}
\newenvironment{romanequation}{%

\incr@eqnumrom@n
\mathdisplay@push
\st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
\mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplayroman{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother
```

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{romanequation}

\def\incr@eqnumrom@n{\refstepcounter{romanequation}\let\incr@eqnumr\@empty}

\renewcommand{\theromanequation}{\roman{romanequation}}

\def\endmathdisplayroman#1{%
  \ifmmode \else \@badmath \fi
  \endmathdisplay@aroman
  $$%
  \global\let\df@label\@empty \global\let\df@tag\@empty
  \global\tag@false \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
  \global\@eqnswfalse
}

\def\endmathdisplay@aroman{%
  \if@eqnsw \gdef\df@tag{\tagform@\theromanequation}\fi
  \if@fleqn \@xp\endmathdisplay@fleqn
  \else \ifx\df@tag\@empty \else \veqno \alt@tag \df@tag \fi
    \ifx\df@label\@empty \else \@xp\ltx@label\@xp{\df@label}\fi
  \fi
  \ifnum\dspbrk@lvl>\m@ne
    \postdisplaypenalty -\@getpen\dspbrk@lvl
    \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne
  \fi
}

\def\print@eqnumrom@n{\tagform@\theromanequation}
\newenvironment{romanequation}{%

\incr@eqnumrom@n
\mathdisplay@push
\st@rredfalse \global\@eqnswtrue
\mathdisplay{equation}%
}{%
  \endmathdisplayroman{equation}%
  \mathdisplay@pop
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{romanequation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{romanequation}

\begin{romanequation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{romanequation}

\begin{romanequation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{romanequation}

\begin{romanequation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{romanequation}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\begin{romanequation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{romanequation}

\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}+1=0
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and its result:
[image]

Comment: Would a similar setup work for numbering figures and theorems?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I see that ref is messed up, but definition used by `amsmath` for `equation` is entangled so it's not easy to pull the counter out. We also have to redefine `\endmathdisplay`. Fixed now.

Comment: @AlanC: For `amsthm` I suppose you can use `\theoremstyle` so it should be easier to handle. Not sure about figures so it may requires defining new environment.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Oops, some typos. Now it should work.